# Move chartjs y axis description

Tags: chart.js

I would like to move the y axis description to the top (because my lables are very long and I need to save some space).

left: original

right: what I would like to have:

[image]

I'm have a stacked bar chart with chartjs 2.8

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any fiddler or plunker? please share if possible

Comment: I don't have an example online. But there are a lot of examples on the Chartjs site: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/line-styles.html

Comment: May be Scale Properties could be a solution https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html

Comment: Found also this: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6305 and this https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6261